# How to do strcmp in textboxes with Matlab

Tags: matlab, strcmp

I would like to know how to compare strings between 2 text boxes in Matlab. Can someone please give some examples?

Answer (score 0):

```
str1=get(handles.edit1,'String');
str2=get(handles.edit2,'String');

if (  strcmp(str1,str2)==1)        
 set(handles.edit3,'String','equal');
else
 set(handles.edit3,'String','not equal');
end
```

str1 and str2 are string variables. string retrieved from textbox form get function and put string into textbox using set function.  and both string variables compared with strcmp function. comparison is equal return 1 otherwise 0